# Siebel default email form fields are appearing as readonly

Tags: siebel

Siebel out of the box form to send email is displaying all fields as readonly.

[image]

- I checked at applet controls and they are not readonly
- BC level fields are not readonly
- BC level readonly properties are been inactivated
- No field user property for readonly there.

I am not sure what's wrong here. Even tried vanilla sif but same issue.

Comment: Check with any responsibilities associated to that view, It may be readonly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was a value missing in the LOV. We added the value and it was fixed.